# Compare two date objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I want to check whether the date object `Thu Apr 29 2021 01:15:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` is before or after the current time, that is `new Date()`.

I tried the basic `<` operator but it doesn't seem to work.

How do I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: May you share a [mcve] of what you have already tried?

Comment: it's basically just `Thu Apr 29 2021 01:15:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) < new Date()`. I tried it out in chrome dev console to get a boolean.

Comment: `Thu Apr 29 2021 01:15:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) < new Date()` isn't valid JavaScript. Do you get an error?

Comment: How do i compare then?

Comment: Where does `Thu Apr 29 2021 01:15:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` come from?

Comment: I don't get anything in result

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: I've created that date object somewhere in the frontend

Comment: But you should get an error message: https://wandbox.org/permlink/FE3dXgRSwcoLSoke

Answer (score 0):

Convert your string to a Date object so that you can compare those two.
Reference: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)

```js
const my_date = new Date("Thu Apr 29 2021 01:15:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)")
const c_date = new Date()

console.log(my_date > c_date)
```

Comment: You don't need the second Date, `new Date(string) > Date.now()` will return the same result.

Answer (score 0):

It should be working with the `<>` operators:

```js
const d1 = new Date("Thu Apr 29 2021 01:15:00 GMT+0530");
let now = new Date();

[d1, now].forEach(d => console.log(d));

console.log(now > d1);          // false because now is less than d1
now.setDate(now.getDate() + 2); // add 2 days to the now date
console.log(now > d1);          // true because now is greater than d1
```